# android as a portable device location

Tags: applications, android-pc

I have connected an Android cellphone to the PC through a MTP connection. it brings a folder under Portable Devices section in My Computer.

I want to get the location of this folder. how can I do that? I right-click and choose properties and it says the Location as: Computer/Mo A.Z

But I want to access it through C drive. is it possible?!

Comment: Which version of android do you have? Also are you rooted?

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible**.

https://superuser.com/questions/369959/how-do-i-access-mtp-devices-on-the-command-line-in-windows

You could try your luck mounting it from a recovery or using `adb push`. Another option would be installing a SSH (or FTP or ...) server on your phone if you want to be able to manipulate files on your device easier.

*(No clue whether this question is a duplicate if it's located on a different SE resource.)*

Answer (score 0):

Here are some workarounds:

1. **Using QtADB**

QtADB is a full-featured tool (designed for windows )and has a plethora of features to manage your droid. Some of these include:

- File manager (copying files and dirs between phone and computer, delete , creation of dirs)
- App manager (installing, removing, creating backs ups etc)
- Shell and  more..

The essence of this is that it alows **mounting of external sd card to a computer without giving annoying notifications**. Check here for more info: [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/)

2. **Using USB MASS STORAGE Enabler (root)**

This is one of the  few apps offering to restore the lost Universal Mass Storage (UMS) option.

1. After downloading the [tool](https://iwf1.com/how-to-mount-android-device-as-usb-mass-storage-ums/) ,connect your device using USB cable to your computer.
2. Open the ‘UMS Enabler’ app and press ‘Enable Mass Storage’. Remember,  give the app root access if it asks.

At this point, you might get various messages by the app, for instance, there a message asking you to set **SELinux** – a Linux module Android uses to make it more secure – to permissive state; this is required for the app to run properly.

Hope this helps

Credits

1. [Any way to get USB Mass Storage instead of MTP?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2023066)
2. [How To Mount Android Device As USB Mass Storage (UMS)?](https://iwf1.com/how-to-mount-android-device-as-usb-mass-storage-ums/)
3. [QtADB  for android](https://qtadb.wordpress.com/features/)